# Aggregate window function output in postgresql (redshift)

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I really want to use the median window function as an aggregate function.

I currently am forced to use the window function in a sub-select, and then aggregate over it like this:

```
SELECT id, MIN(avg) AS mean, MIN(median) AS median, COUNT(*)
    FROM (
    SELECT id, AVG(metric) OVER(PARTITION BY id), MEDIAN(metric) OVER(PARTITION BY id)
    FROM data_table
    )
GROUP BY id;
```

Is there a way to aggregate over a window function result so there's only one SELECT statement?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, your example query could be rewritten:

```
SELECT id,
    AVG(metric),
    MEDIAN(metric),
    COUNT(*)
FROM data_table
GROUP BY id;
```

But I'm wondering if you just picked a poor example that happens to be mathematically capable of simplification.  This is a special case because the subquery and the main query are aggregating on the same field, and the outer aggregates are picking a minimum from what would be a set of identical values.

If that's not the case and your actual query and subquery are *not* grouping by the same field, then the answer is no, you need a subquery for two reasons:

First, by ANSI definition, window functions are evaluated *after* the `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `HAVING` clauses.  There is no clause to specify your desired behavior of aggregating after a window function, so you must use a subquery or CTE.

Second, even if you eliminated the windowing from the `OVER()` clause you need to `GROUP BY` data you only know *after* the first round of aggregation has been completed.